# Producing beamer handout in Scientific Workplace v 5.5

Tags: beamer

Does anyone know how to tell `beamer` to produce a handout from a `beamer` file, i.e., print one page for each full screen and not one page for each line that is added?

Comment: Could you edit your title so that it reflects your actual question. Using only `Scientific Workplace 5.5` is not sufficient. On the other hand, have you consulted the help file for Scientific Workplace? Or the website for it?

Comment: Can you please provide a simple small document showing how are you currently producing the handout?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this software, but, if you have access to the preamble of your document, you have just to add the option `[handout]` in your `\documentclass` declaration

Example:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scientific Workplace 5.5, hitting the preview button, without compiling produces a handout format. Of course this may not be what you are looking for but this is what I get:

[image]

The preview obtained is:

[image]

The above document is created by default under `FILE > NEW > Other Documents > Slides Beamer`